How to change the bottom position of Notistack Snackbar?
I have specific requirements for my snackbar notifications:

Each snackbar needs to be positioned 50px from the bottom of the screen
This positioning should only apply to specific snackbar notifications, not globally through SnackbarProvider
I need to maintain other settings like variant and horizontal positioning

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions.
I've been stuck on this issue for hours. 
Thank you in advance!
I'm trying to adjust the bottom position of a specific Notistack Snackbar in my React application.
Currently, I'm using it like this:
import { enqueueSnackbar } from 'notistack';

enqueueSnackbar('Test message', {
  variant: 'success',
  anchorOrigin: {
    vertical: 'bottom',
    horizontal: 'right',
  },
  style: {
    bottom: '500px',
  },
  classes: {
    root: { bottom: 500 }
  },
});


As I see, the options parameter in enqueueSnackbar does not have a class with styles, you can customize styles through props content extend from SharedProps.
Content props can pass a node or a callback that returns a node, here you can use a callback that receives 2 arguments, key and message, from enqueueSnackbar.
Below is an example code, I am using the SnackbarContent component of MUI but there is a problem that there is no way to get the default style of the notistack itself, for example, the blue success color of variant="success". We have to customize the corresponding style ourselves, like I am setting bgColor with success.main, which is the color of the system's design system. You should try and write it into separate components, which is also a way:
enqueueSnackbar('Test message', {
      anchorOrigin: {
        vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'right'
      },
      content: (key, message) => (
        <div style={{ marginBottom: '200px' }} key={key}>
          <SnackbarContent
            message={message}
            sx={{ bgcolor: 'success.main', color: 'white' }}
          />
        </div>
      )
    });

